# How to calculate Angle to (Kabba)Mecca from current location with android compass

Tags: android

How to calculate  Angle to (Kabba)Mecca from current location with android compass. I am using following code, but it is not giving correct angle

```
Location currentLoc = MYGPS.getLocation(DirectionActivity.this);
            currentLat = currentLoc.getLatitude();
            currentLng = currentLoc.getLongitude();
Location KaabaLoc = new Location("GPS");
            KaabaLoc.setLatitude(KaabaLat);
            KaabaLoc.setLongitude(KaabaLng);

            private float bearing = KaabaLoc.bearingTo(currentLoc)%(float)(2*Math.PI);
```

Answer (score 2):

try to implement this, hope it will help:

```
double angle = Math.atan2(dlat, dlon); // in radians
```

This is assuming your arrow is pointing along the horizontal axis(due east) by default. You might have to tweak it by whatever direction your arrow drawable is pointing. For example, if it's pointing a constant 90 degrees off, just rotate it an additional 0.5*PI rads to align it.

[for more info please read this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class

```
class GreatCircleBearing{
static public double initial (double lat1, double long1, double lat2,   double long2)
{
    return (_bearing(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) + 360.0) % 360;
}

static public double final1(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
    return (_bearing(lat2, long2, lat1, long1) + 180.0) % 360;
}

static private double _bearing(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
    final double  degToRad = Math.PI / 180.0;
    double phi1 = lat1 * degToRad;
    double phi2 = lat2 * degToRad;
    double lam1 = long1 * degToRad;
    double lam2 = long2 * degToRad;

    return Math.atan2(Math.sin(lam2-lam1)*Math.cos(phi2),
        Math.cos(phi1)*Math.sin(phi2) - Math.sin(phi1)*Math.cos(phi2)*Math.cos(lam2-lam1)
    ) * 180/Math.PI;
}
}
```

then call with source and destination location point. It will return you the desired angle

```
GreatCircleBearing.initial(latitude1, longitude1, KaabaLat, KaabaLng)
```